# ng2 - passing information from siblings component directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am learning Angular 2 by creating simple projects, here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tt0zLudPqhrBfG0iffj1) of the app.

It has two custom made components,

1. video-list.ts
2. video-player.ts

Both of the above components are displayed in the `app.ts` compontent using their directives.

The video player component should show any clicked song as the `{{ nowPlaying }}` variable, as the list of song are in the video-list component i can't understand how to pass the clicked song item and display its title on the video-player component.

Though, video player component has a `@Input`  decorator for the `nowPlaying` object variable but i have no idea how to reach the selected object via the app component from the video list component.

I also added a `nowPlayingDefault` variable in the app component to pass it to the video player component by default.

Here is the code: (https://plnkr.co/edit/Tt0zLudPqhrBfG0iffj1)

**app.ts**

```
// root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { VideoList } from './video-list';
import { VideoPlayer } from './video-player';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class='block'>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2> 
      <video-player [nowPlaying]='nowPlayingDefault'></video-player> 
      <hr>
      <video-lists></video-lists>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  nowPlayingDefault:string = 'Please select a song.';
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ 
    App, 
    VideoList,
    VideoPlayer
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**video-list.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'video-lists',
  template: ` 
    <div id='video-lists' class='block'>

      <div style='text-align: center;'>
        From Video List Component
      </div>

      <a href='' style='display: block'
        *ngFor='let item of items'
        (click)='selectSong( item, $event )'>
        {{ item.title }}
      </a>

    </div>
  ` 
})

export class VideoList {
  test: string = 'sos';
  items = [
    {
      'title' : 'yo test',
      'url'   : '823ery783dh.mp3'
    },
    {
      'title' : 'yall rappin',
      'url'   : '25wd13edc1.mp3'
    }
  ];

  selectSong( item, event )
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( item );
  }

}
```

**video-player.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'video-player',
  template: `
    <div id='video-player' class='block'>
      <div style='text-align: center'>~ Video Player Block ~ </div>
      <div style='color: blue;'>{{ nowPlaying }}</div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class VideoPlayer {
  @Input() nowPlaying: string = 'Please select a song.';
}
```

How can i display the clicked song title from video list component to the video player component's `nowPlaying` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an `@Output()` to be able to notify

```
export class VideoList {
  @Output() selectedChange:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();      

  test: string = 'sos';
  items = [
    {
      'title' : 'yo test',
      'url'   : '823ery783dh.mp3'
    },
    {
      'title' : 'yall rappin',
      'url'   : '25wd13edc1.mp3'
    }
  ];

  selectSong( item, event )
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( item );
    this.selectedChange.emit(item);
  }
}
```

and bind to the `@Output()` event and update a property when new values are emitted

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class='block'>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2> 
      <video-player [nowPlaying]='nowPlayingDefault'></video-player> 
      <hr>
      <video-lists (selectedChange)="nowPlaying=$event"></video-lists>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

Comment: This is giving an `Error: (SystemJS) Error: Template parse errors:(…)`

Can you explain this line `(selectedChange)="nowPlaying="event"`

Comment: Three was a typo - fixed. When `this.selectedChange.emit(item)` is called then the expression `xxx` in `(selectedChange)="xxx" is evaluated and `$event` contains the passed `item` value. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ contains all the information.